# How to Import cPanel Mail (raw - from mail folder)?

Tags: email, cpanel

I have a website which was hosting on a different server, including emails for that domain. For some reason I lost access to that server. The email was setup using cPanel Mail.

Now I am setting up that domain again with a newly purchased "Ultimate Hosting" from GoDaddy.

I have a backup to the "Mail" folder. I want to know how can I restore that mail folder?

Following the main folder structure of the raw folder backup I have.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i77Gu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved.. for anyone looking for similar thing, here is the solutions.

I created a new mail account in GoDaddy cPanel Mail with the same name as previous.
After that I overwrite all the raw files using FTP client.
Bang! All the email are now recovered.

Thanks